# SATA port multiplier: Drives not recognized

Tags: bios, sata, ahci

I have a port multiplier with a JMicron JB321 chipset. It connects, power ups and only shows the Drive that is connected on the first port.

My SATA Config is at AHCI. My Board is: GA-H81M-SP2V

A little insight into how i can get it to work would be appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all SATA controllers support port multipliers. The one in your H81 chipset does not - see [its datasheet](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/8-series-chipset-pch-datasheet.pdf), page 512: *"The PCH SATA controller does not support Port Multipliers."*

If your motherboard has SATA ports controlled by some other chip, try using one of those ports. But based on what I can see at its [specs page](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4664#sp) (see the section under "Storage") I don't think it does, as all of the SATA ports are listed under "chipset".

Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks for a precise yet a detailed answer. Well I do have another trick up my sleeve to increase SATA port count xD

Comment: Yep... if you have a spare PCI-E slot you could add a SATA controller card, and you could pick one with a chip that does support PM. (Sadly, this table: https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/SATA_hardware_features has not been updated for five years.) Booting from such will require a little playing around with drivers, but if you're just using them for data you should be fine. (and thank you for the upvote and best answer!)

Comment: I have used up m PCIe Slot (1 for GPU and other for USB3 add in card) so that can be done. What i can do is add an external USB to SATA converter inside the case to allow more Ports. I don't need the speed anyway. Just data retrieval and stuff. Thanks for the help! :D